# Is it correct to say "I win. He lose" or "I win. He loses"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Say, Tom is playing chess with Bob and Mary is watching them playing.

Tom has **just** checkmated Bob and right after the checkmate he turned to Mary and say "**I win. He lose**" or "**I win. He loses**"?.

If Tom says to Bob, then it is easy because Tom will say "**I win. You lose**". We don't care whether it is an exclamation or the simple present tense.

But if Tom says to Mary about Bob, I don't know if Tom should say "**I win. He lose**" or "**I win. He loses**"?

**Is it an exclamation or the simple present tense?**

Comment: "I win and he loses" is simply a statement (though in a game of two players it's hardly necessary to mention the loser unless you intend to be unkind). "He lose" sounds like broken English.

Comment: You must add the "s" to conjugate the verb *to lose* in the third person singular.  He/she/it loses.

Comment: Why do you think exclamations don't follow subject-verb agreement?

Comment: “He lose” is never, ever correct. That is, third-person conjugation always applies.

Answer (score 3):

The outcome of the game is technically in the past as soon as it is decided, so the common phrasing is "**I won, he lost**."

Furthermore, people know that in a chess game if one person wins the other must lose. So just "**I won**" makes the most sense and would be used instead of "**I won, he lost**." The "he lost" is just repetitive .

"I win, he loses." may be correct, but is sounds very immature, something that a young child may say. The same is true with "I win, you lose." That is a phrase kid's say to immaturely rub in their victory.

Comment: In speaking, we often use the simple present in a context like this.

Comment: @Lambie you must speak British English?

Comment: To me, as a British English speaker, it's natural to say "You win" to concede defeat in a two-handed game - so I don't find "I win" particularly childish.

Comment: @KateBunting right, in AmE we sometimes (but not often) use "you win" to concede also, but not when telling someone else the result. To relay the outcome "I win" doesn't work well. Although, kid's use it "rub in" their victory which is why it comes across as childish. Since he is trying to tell the observer the outcome, "I won" would almost always be the only version used here (US).

Comment: Not at all. :) This use has a name: performative utterance. [Searle] See Wikipedia for a full explanation. Performative utterances are made on the spot. This has nothing to do with British or American English. For example: if you toss a coin with someone, you say: Heads I win, Tails I lose. You then toss the coin. You then would say if heads comes up: I win, you lose.

Comment: @Lambie Of course I have heard and used "Heads I win, tails I lose," but I have literally never heard "I win, you lose" after the toss, only "I won." Maybe it depends on location...

Answer (score 1):

We focus on 'who wins/won', not 'who loses/lost'.

We usually say 'I won'.

Simple present tense-

I lose. You lose. We lose. They lose. I win. You win. We win. They win.

He loses. She loses. The man loses. It loses. He wins. She wins. It wins. The man wins. (-**s** for the third person singular.)

Simple past tense-

I lost. You lost. We lost. They lost. He lost. She lost. The man lost. I won. You won. He won. She won. They won.

It is better to use the simple past tense.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of an exclamation mark indicates that it is not an exclamation, and even if it were, the term "exclamation" simply indicates that it is said with especially high emotion. It doesn't affect the grammar. You might be confusing an exclamation with an interjection. Interjections do not need to be complete sentences, and so can lack a verb and/or subject, but if they do have a subject and a verb, the subject and verb should agree. Or perhaps you are confusing "exclamation" with "imperative", but it doesn't really make sense to have an imperative in the third person.